# Add accept="image/*" attribute to input field in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I want to add client side validation for file upload using HTML5 "accept" attribute and ExtJs "inputAttrTpl" config.
My ExtJs code is following (ExtJs 4.1):

```
{
              xtype : 'filefield',
              action : 'upload',
              name : 'file',
              inputAttrTpl: 'accept="image/*"',
              hideLabel : true,
              buttonOnly : true,
              anchor : '100%',
              buttonText : 'Upload img...',
              margin: 5
}
```

But when I am checking file field in firebug, it doesn't contain "accept" attribute.
Can you suggest some solutions for this issue?
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: It does exactly what you describe. `<input id="filefield-1010-inputEl" type="text" accept="image/*" size="1" ...`

Comment: The 'accept' attribute is actually being added to the text input in this case, it actually needs to be on the file input to work. The answer by @Neil McGuigan below seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 9):

```
{
  xtype:'filefield',
  listeners:{
    afterrender:function(cmp){
      cmp.fileInputEl.set({
        accept:'audio/*'
      });
    }
  }
}
```

You can set accept to "" to remove the restriction.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3V9dM/)

Comment: But with this restriction don't ensure that the file is an audio/image/whatever file, because you can change the type of file in the popup window and select any file. How could I check in client side that the file is an image???

Comment: @Alavaros you can use the HTML5 file api to check the type of the file before upload.

Comment: Besides this listener, you also need to override the reset method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554621/accept-image-in-filefield-extjs/26017499

Answer (score 0):

```
{
        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
        name: 'file',
        fieldLabel: 'Photo',
        labelWidth: 50,
        allowBlank: false,
        buttonText: 'SelectPhoto',
        anchor: '100%',
        reset: function () {
            var me = this,
                clear = me.clearOnSubmit;
            if (me.rendered) {
                me.button.reset(clear);
                me.fileInputEl = me.button.fileInputEl;
                me.fileInputEl.set({
                    accept: 'image/*'
                });
                if (clear) {
                    me.inputEl.dom.value = '';
                }
                me.callParent();
            }},
        listeners:{
            change: 'fileInputChange',
            afterrender:function(cmp){
                cmp.fileInputEl.set({
                    accept:'image/*'
                });
            }
        },
        regex: /(.)+((\.png)|(\.jpg)|(\.jpeg)(\w)?)$/i,
        regexText: 'Only PNG and JPEG image formats are accepted'
    }
```